# Share Point Calculating leave days Available

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a leave request web part that I would like to show output on .I want to calculate available leave days per year .How can I do that using Information in share Point list

Comment: Can you please add more details about your scenario to the question? It is not easy to answer your question as it is written now

Comment: Thank you for responding.I have a Leave Request web part and I want to show all the leave request with status approved from my leave request share Point list.[Getting all leave request items with status of Approved but the Start Date is greater than today]

Answer (score 0):

You can show approved leave request with start date greater than today by putting filter in your view settings.

Create/modify view, go to filter section, select radio button "Show items only when the following is true". In first drop-down select "Status" Column is equal to "Approved". Then select radio button "And". Then in second drop-down select "Start Date" is greater than [Today].

Hope this helps.